# nest tag inside link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

How to nest "strong" tag inside link_to helper

is this ok?(html_safe)

```
<li><%= link_to "Logged in as <strong>#{current_user.username}</strong>".html_safe, current_user %></li>
```

or mb there're other methods to do this.

thanks!

Comment: yes, using html_safe is ok here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's special form of the link_to helper made for this use case:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to current_user do %>
    Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.username %></strong>
  <% end %>
</li>
```